# Is there an easy way to fix the trim below the bay window? or better to replace?

Tags: repair, paint, exterior, trim, caulk

[image]

What would I replace with? I was thinking I might be able to fill the hole with liquid wood or something.

Comment: The hole suggests the trim is made from plastic more than wood.  Something like bondo should work to fill and match.  Painting will be harder to match.